# Uso de *peña* como grupo de gente

Tags: etimología

La acepción principal de la palabra *peña* en el diccionario es la de una piedra grande o un monte rocoso. Sin embargo, también usamos esta palabra frecuentemente para hacer referencia a un grupo de personas, normalmente organizadas con fines recreativos.

He consultado el DLE y [da el mismo origen](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SUo0flu) para los dos grupos de acepciones: el latín *pinna*, que parece razonable para el sentido de piedra, pero no veo la relación con el grupo de personas.

¿Alguien sabe cómo se derivó este significado?

Comment: Ni idea pero *peña* se parece mucho a *piña* que tambien puede ser un grupo de gente unida ¿Tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que podría referirse a un *montón* de gente, pensando en "montón" como una pila de cosas, o un montón de piedras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de consultar algunas fichas del Fichero General, alguna he encontrado que me ha puesto sobre la pista, confirmada después por algunos textos del CORDE.

En 1869 se funda en Madrid el círculo social privado de [La Gran Peña](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Gran_Pe%C3%B1a), un conjunto de militares españoles procedentes del Estado Mayor y del cuerpo de Ingenieros que hacían tertulia en el café Suizo madrileño. En 1914 se ocupó un edificio de la Gran Vía como su sede social, inaugurándose en 1916 por los reyes de España. Entre los peñistas más ilustres se han encontrado los políticos como José Canalejas, y José Calvo Sotelo, así como también miembros de la realeza como Alfonso XIII, y desde 1975 Juan Carlos I.

No cuesta trabajo imaginar que a este círculo social se le comenzara a llamar simplemente "la peña", y por extensión se usara este nombre para designar a cualquier grupo de personas organizado con fines recreativos.  Buscando en la hemeroteca de la BNE se encuentran multitud de casos de "la gran peña" en periódicos haciendo alusión a este círculo, lo que denota su gran importancia dentro de la vida social de la capital española, como en el siguiente ejemplo escrito al poco de su creación:

> El año último, y bajo el estraño y singular nombre de *La Gran Peña*, fundóse una sociedad que alcanza ya desahogada y venturosa existencia. La base de aquella fueron al principio oficiales y jefes de artillería, que abandonaron su antiguo punto de reunión en el café de la Iberia para juntarse en el piso entresuelo de la casa del Suizo.
>
> La Época (Madrid). 17/12/1869, n.º 6.797, página 4.

Esto sin duda impulsó este uso de la palabra "peña", que para 1925 había entrado en el diccionario de la RAE de esta forma:

> **PEÑA.** f. Corro o grupo de amigos o camaradas. || **2.** Nombre que toman algunos círculos de recreo.

La primera acepción hará referencia a los grupos de gente que se reunían como lo hacían los de La Gran Peña, y la segunda deja claro que las propias asociaciones o círculos que promovían estas reuniones se quisieran denominar a sí mismas como la Peña original.

Lo curioso es que en el periódico citado arriba se cuenta el origen del nombre La Gran Peña:

> Espliquemos ahora el origen del titulo *La Peña*, que lleva el círculo de la calle de Alcalá.
>        Si nuestras noticias no son equivocadas, parece que en el colegio de artillería sé llama *peña* al alumno de carácter reconcentrado á quien le agradan poco los ruidosos placeres del mundo.
>        Así para designar al que se hallaba en semejante caso, se decía entre los antiguos habitantes del alcázar de Segovia:
>        —Fulano ó Zutano es un *peña*.
>        El apodo hizo fortuna, y se aplicó, no solo á los alumnos de la academia, sino á los oficiales que fuera ya de ella conservaban sus primitivos gustos y aficiones.
>        Poco después dióse el nombre de *La peña* al saloncilo del cafe de *La Iberia*, donde se reunían invariablemente todas
>   las noches —antes y después del teatro,— los oficiales de artillería.

Comment: En Argentina se le llama *peña* a algunas asociaciones o clubes o grupos de aficionados a algo (en mi ciudad hay una Peña Fotográfica, por ejemplo) y, en el noroeste del país, *peñas folclóricas* a salones donde se toca, se baila o se escucha y ve bailar música típica local, generalmente mientras se comen platos también típicos. No tenía idea de que la palabra tuviese este origen.

Comment: Gracias por la investigación, Charlie. El origen de este significado parece muy claro, entonces.

Comment: En Chile sólo se usa en **peña folclórica** y hace alusión a un festival o evento floclórico que incluye música.